# AWS eb's docker setting is not work if I use only containerPort without hostPort.(Multi-container Docker)

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ecs, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

Elastic Beanstalk: 
Multi-container Docker running on 64bit Amazon Linux/2.11.6

It works well with `eb deploy`.

```
{
  "AWSEBDockerrunVersion": 2,
  "containerDefinitions": [
        {
      "name": "nextjs",
      "image": "node:8.15.0-alpine",
      "essential": true,
      "memory": 128,
      "portMappings": [
        {
          "hostPort": 3000,
          "containerPort": 3000
        }           
      ]
    }
}
```

It is not work. ECS task is stopped.

```
{
  "AWSEBDockerrunVersion": 2,
  "containerDefinitions": [
        {
      "name": "nextjs",
      "image": "node:8.15.0-alpine",
      "essential": true,
      "memory": 128,
      "portMappings": [
        {
          "containerPort": 3000
        }           
      ]
    }
}
```

Log after `eb deploy`

```
019-01-14 12:59:49    INFO    Environment update is starting.
2019-01-14 12:59:58    INFO    Deploying new version to instance(s).
2019-01-14 13:00:15    WARN    Failed to start ECS task, retrying...
2019-01-14 13:00:15    ERROR   Failed to start ECS task: arn:aws:ecs:us-west-2:625650244102:task/492d1f1e-5fad-4be8-9c7b-6aebb5af157a is STOPPED.
2019-01-14 13:00:15    ERROR   ECS task stopped due to: Essential container in task exited. (nextjs:
nginx-proxy: )
2019-01-14 13:00:16    INFO    ECS task: arn:aws:ecs:us-west-2:625650244102:task/492d1f1e-5fad-4be8-9c7b-6aebb5af157a is STOPPED.
2019-01-14 13:00:19    INFO    Starting new ECS task with awseb-deeo-dev-ubn3e2cd52:27.
2019-01-14 13:00:23    INFO    ECS task: arn:aws:ecs:us-west-2:625650244102:task/62386f55-f50c-4e41-9496-b1ec59694e7e is RUNNING.
2019-01-14 13:00:30    INFO    New application version was deployed to running EC2 instances.
2019-01-14 13:00:30    INFO    Environment update completed successfully.
```

Ignore typos.

I do not know why it is not work if I use `containerPort` only. Anybody help me?

Answer (score 0):

Solved.

Give enough memory for nextjs docker environment over 256. 
But It cause to make multi instances to make set various memory. So, make other containers' memory same.